# Broken reference Error log in Layout magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, error-log

> Actually i am facing this error due to layout mistake.please guide
>   me.

```
   [2019-02-18 06:28:17] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'category.cms', but their parents are different: 'columns.top' and 'category.view.container' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:28:44] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'category.cms', but their parents are different: 'columns.top' and 'category.view.container' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:29:38] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'category.cms', but their parents are different: 'columns.top' and 'category.view.container' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:29:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'category.cms', but their parents are different: 'columns.top' and 'category.view.container' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:29:56] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'category.cms', but their parents are different: 'columns.top' and 'category.view.container' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'global.notices', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'menu' element cannot be added as child to 'page.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.breadcrumbs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'formkey' element cannot be added as child to 'page.formkey', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.title' element cannot be added as child to 'main.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'messages' element cannot be added as child to 'page.messages', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' element cannot be added as child to 'page.main.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'legal' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_area' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_window' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2019-02-18 06:30:50] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' tries to reorder itself towards 'header.inner.left', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
```